# Using papaparse after loading script dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, papaparse

### ORIGINAL

I'm loading [Papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) on the fly in my Javascript app like this:

```
$.getScript('path/to/papaparse.js',function() {
    //below script
});
```

Then I get the file for parsing like this.

```
$('#csv_file').parse({
    delimiter: ",",
    worker: true,
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    before: function(file,inputElement) {
        console.log(file);
        console.log(inputElement);
    },
    error: function(err, file, inputElement, reason) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(err);
        console.log(file);
        console.log(inputElement);
        console.log(reason);
    },
    step: function(results,parser) {
        console.log(results);
        console.log(parser);
    },
    complete: function(results,file) {
        console.log(results);
        console.log(file);
    }
});
```

None of my `console.log`'s in the `step`-callback fires, but they print from the `before`- and `complete`-callbacks.

```
before:
    file:
        File {}
        lastModified: 1437396586321
        lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 20 2015 14:49:46 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
        name: "normal.csv"
        size: 254743
        type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        webkitRelativePath: ""
    inputElement:
        <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" class="form-control half">
complete:
    results: undefined
    file: undefined
```

Can someone tell me why **a)** it's not returning anything in my `step`-callback and **b)** why it's returning `undefined` in my `complete`-callback?

### UPDATE

I have added the `SCRIPT_PATH` as suggested in the comments like so:

```
$.getScript('path/to/papaparse.js',function() {
    Papa.SCRIPT_PATH = config.basedir + '/app/lib/papaparse/papaparse.min.js';
    // Papa script
});
```

And changed my before to this:

```
before: function(file,inputElement) {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(inputElement);
    return { action : 'continue' }
},
```

However still get undefined.

Comment: Did you do this? http://papaparse.com/faq#async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was quite simple. `complete: function(results,file)` and `step:function(results,parser)` needs to be in the config file as this is per file config.

Obviously step wouldn't run if it is not defined per file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try explicitly returning an `{ action="continue" }` in your before function? 
You could be running into a variant of this issue - https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/18

Comment: I've updated my question with your suggestion. Still no luck